# Maximum and minimum values for a curve

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Considering the curve:

$$
f(x) = x²
$$

Does the curve $f$ have a maximum in the open interval $-1 < x < 1$? A minimum?

I had a hard time interpreting this question. My first thought was:

Yes, it has a maximum. The maximum value in the open interval $-1 < x < 1$ is

$$
lim_{x -> 1} x² = lim_{x -> -1} x² = 1
$$

The minimum value is naturally

$$
f(0) = 0² = 0
$$

However, I started wondering if thinking this way about the problem is wrong. Would it be more accurate to consider the problem as the *whole* curve $f$ having a maximum and a minimum in $-1 < x < 1$? Thus, arguing that it does NOT have a maximum in the interval (or any maximums at all, for that matter) but a minimum in $x = 0$, seeing as

$$
f'(x) = 2x, 2x = 0 \rightarrow x = 0
$$

Which way would be the most natural way to interpret the question?

Comment: So you found that the maximum value occurs at the points 1 and -1.  Are those points in (-1, 1)?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "the whole curve $f$ having a maximum and a minimum in $-1 \le x \le 1$"? As opposed to what you were doing earlier.

Comment: BTW, the plural of "maximum" is "maxima".  I like Ross's answer.  There's no need to consider derivatives when you know what this parabola looks like, unless someone says you have to use derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the interval contained $-1$ and $1$, which it does not, then the curve would have what we call *local maximums* at the endpoints of the closed interval, when considering the curve restricted to the interval. But the interval is open, so there are *no endpoints* to consider.

So there is no real need to pin down the intent of the question. There are *no local or global* **maximums**, but *one* local and global *minimum*, at the point $(0, 0)$ as you note.

Comment: I decided to write my answer as I did in the beginning of the question, but with a small side-note:

"...or $f'(x) = 2x, 2x = 0 \rightarrow x = 0$, which only gives us a minimumvalue in x = 0 and no maximum value. I assumed you meant the minimum and maximum value in the said interval." I feel this is a natural way of answering, seeing as we have yet to mention global and local maximums.

Comment: This is fine. I think that's the intent of the question. I hope this helps. Just note that $x = 1, x=-1$ are not maximums on the interval, nor on the curve as a whole. Can you see why?

Comment: Because $x = 1$ and $x = -1$ is not in the interval $(-1, 1)$?

Comment: Exactly. Limits aren't appropriate for determining maximums here: a maximum or minimum must be a point actually contained in a given domain, here, an interval.

Comment: Ok, I think that a better approach would be the rewrite my whole assignment (I'm pretty crazy about handing in nicely written papers.) So, the most accurate response would be to skip the whole first part with limits, seeing as limits are an inappropiate method for determinating the maximum and minimums of a function? (That's what we have derivatives for, I suppose.)

Comment: That's correct. Derivatives will point to candidates, as will endpoints of *closed intervals* - all points to "test" to identify if and when a point evaluates to a maximum or minimum of a function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asked to consider the curve over $(-1,1)$, that is what you should do.  The fact that there is a natural way to extend it to all of $\Bbb R$ is not relevant.  The critical point is that a maximum must be attained and there is no point in $(-1,1)$ where $f(x)=1$.  This is the difference between a supremum (which need not be attained) and a maximum.